# Find index to QStandardItemModel upon QCompleter activated call

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qstandarditemmodel, qcompleter

I am writing up a GUI with a editfield in PyQt5 using QCompleter to allow the user to select the input from a pop up list. The list is built into a QStandardItem and provided to QCompleter. What I need is the index to the row in QStandardItem model, when the user has selected an item from the pop up list.

I have tried to study the doc https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html and found a section called

Iterating Through Completions
To retrieve a single candidate string, call setCompletionPrefix() with the text that needs to be completed and call currentCompletion().

This is not useful in my case, because there is a risk that duplicated item exists in my QStandardItem model, e.g. ['cat,'cat','dog']. Depending if user select first or second cat, there are two different Ids associated with it. Therefore, it is important to get the index of QStandardItem model for the item that user has selected.

```py
self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

#Merge the lists Id, IdCompound, self.SCL_Name together using zip. Id, IdCompount are int, while self.SCL_Name is str

ziplist1 = list(zip(Id, IdCompound, self.SCL_Name))
ziplist2 = list(zip(Id, IdCompound, self.SCL_OtherNames))

#Append the fields in ziplist1 and ziplist2 into 
for name in ziplist1:
    row = list()
    for col in name:
        cell = QtGui.QStandardItem(col) #Has made sure that everything is a string
        row.append(cell)
    self.model.appendRow(row)

for name in ziplist2:
    row = list()
    for col in name:
        cell = QtGui.QStandardItem(col)
        row.append(cell)
    self.model.appendRow(row)

self.completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter()
self.completer.setModel(self.model)
self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
self.completer.activated.connect(self.complete_excipient_input)
self.completer.setCompletionColumn(2)
```

what should I do in self.completer.activated.connect(self.complete_excipient_input) in order to get index in the self.model corresponding to the user selected item?

Edit

I have tried to run the code example provided by @eyllanesc and it works fine. However, when I apply the code into my own code, I get error message stating QObject::connect: Cannot connect QCompleter::activated(QModelIndex) to

```
(null)::onActivated(QModelIndex)
```

and 
    Exception has occurred: TypeError
    connect() failed between activated(QModelIndex) and onActivated()

Below is my code. It is generated in QtDesigner and subsequently converted to python code.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main_v01.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import EBM_DB_tools as tool

class Ui_mainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(1195, 818)
        mainWindow.setWindowOpacity(2.0)
        mainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        mainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonFollowStyle)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineedit_api = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_api.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 143, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineedit_api.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_api.setObjectName("lineedit_api")
        self.pb_apiinsert = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_apiinsert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 130, 75, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pb_apiinsert.setFont(font)
        self.pb_apiinsert.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pb_apiinsert.setObjectName("pb_apiinsert")
        self.api_amount = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.api_amount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(178, 130, 142, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.api_amount.setFont(font)
        self.api_amount.setObjectName("api_amount")
        self.ItemTable = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.ItemTable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 270, 471, 281))
        self.ItemTable.setObjectName("ItemTable")
        self.dropdown_apiunit = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 130, 80, 26))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setObjectName("dropdown_apiunit")
        self.dropdown_apiunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_apiunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_apiunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_apiunit.addItem("")
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 570, 221, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel.setFont(font)
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel.setObjectName("pb_BatchRegisterLabel")
        self.pb_removeTableEntry = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_removeTableEntry.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 390, 75, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pb_removeTableEntry.setFont(font)
        self.pb_removeTableEntry.setObjectName("pb_removeTableEntry")
        self.lineedit_projectno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_projectno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 50, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_projectno.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_projectno.setText("")
        self.lineedit_projectno.setObjectName("lineedit_projectno")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 50, 21, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineedit_formulationno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_formulationno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 50, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_formulationno.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_formulationno.setText("")
        self.lineedit_formulationno.setObjectName("lineedit_formulationno")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(840, 50, 21, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineedit_apino = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_apino.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 50, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_apino.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_apino.setText("")
        self.lineedit_apino.setObjectName("lineedit_apino")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 50, 21, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineedit_batchno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_batchno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(980, 50, 71, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_batchno.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_batchno.setText("")
        self.lineedit_batchno.setObjectName("lineedit_batchno")
        self.dropdown_processtype = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.dropdown_processtype.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 291, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.dropdown_processtype.setFont(font)
        self.dropdown_processtype.setObjectName("dropdown_processtype")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(0, "")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 141, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.textEdit_comment = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_comment.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 300, 511, 251))
        self.textEdit_comment.setObjectName("textEdit_comment")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 260, 151, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 20, 151, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1070, 30, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setFont(font)
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setObjectName("PushButton_NNCnoImport")
        self.pb_formulationRegister = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_formulationRegister.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 570, 221, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pb_formulationRegister.setFont(font)
        self.pb_formulationRegister.setObjectName("pb_formulationRegister")
        self.TextEdit_api = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.TextEdit_api.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 130, 191, 26))
        self.TextEdit_api.setObjectName("TextEdit_api")
        self.TextEdit_Excipient = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.TextEdit_Excipient.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 170, 191, 26))
        self.TextEdit_Excipient.setObjectName("TextEdit_Excipient")
        self.PushButton_Scan = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PushButton_Scan.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1070, 60, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.PushButton_Scan.setFont(font)
        self.PushButton_Scan.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.PushButton_Scan.setObjectName("PushButton_Scan")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 100, 141, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 143, 26))
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setCompleter(self.completer)

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setObjectName("lineedit_ExcipientName")
        self.lineedit_excipientamount = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_excipientamount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 170, 142, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineedit_excipientamount.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_excipientamount.setObjectName("lineedit_excipientamount")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 170, 80, 26))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setObjectName("dropdown_excipientunit")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.addItem("")
        self.pb_excipientinsert = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_excipientinsert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 170, 75, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pb_excipientinsert.setFont(font)
        self.pb_excipientinsert.setObjectName("pb_excipientinsert")
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(mainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1195, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(mainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_api, self.api_amount)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.api_amount, self.dropdown_apiunit)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.dropdown_apiunit, self.pb_apiinsert)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.pb_apiinsert, self.lineedit_ExcipientName)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_ExcipientName, self.lineedit_excipientamount)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_excipientamount, self.dropdown_excipientunit)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.dropdown_excipientunit, self.pb_excipientinsert)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.pb_excipientinsert, self.ItemTable)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.ItemTable, self.textEdit_comment)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.textEdit_comment, self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel, self.lineedit_projectno)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_projectno, self.lineedit_formulationno)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_formulationno, self.lineedit_apino)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_apino, self.lineedit_batchno)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_batchno, self.dropdown_processtype)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.dropdown_processtype, self.pb_removeTableEntry)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineedit_api.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "API NNCNo"))
        self.pb_apiinsert.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Insert"))
        self.api_amount.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Amount"))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setItemText(0, _translate("mainWindow", "mg"))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setItemText(1, _translate("mainWindow", "mg/tablet"))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setItemText(2, _translate("mainWindow", "% (w/w)"))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setItemText(3, _translate("mainWindow", "mg/capsule"))
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Batch Register and Label"))
        self.pb_removeTableEntry.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Remove"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "-"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "-"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "-"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(1, _translate("mainWindow", "option 1"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(2, _translate("mainWindow", "option 2"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(3, _translate("mainWindow", "option 3"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(4, _translate("mainWindow", "option 4"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(5, _translate("mainWindow", "option 5"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(6, _translate("mainWindow", "option 6"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(7, _translate("mainWindow", "option 7"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(8, _translate("mainWindow", "User specify"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Process Type"))
        self.textEdit_comment.setHtml(_translate("mainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Comment"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "NNC No"))
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Import"))
        self.pb_formulationRegister.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Register Formulation"))
        self.TextEdit_api.setHtml(_translate("mainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.TextEdit_Excipient.setHtml(_translate("mainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.PushButton_Scan.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Scan"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Comments"))
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Excipient Name"))
        self.lineedit_excipientamount.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Amount"))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setItemText(0, _translate("mainWindow", "mg"))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setItemText(1, _translate("mainWindow", "mg/tablet"))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setItemText(2, _translate("mainWindow", "% (w/w)"))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setItemText(3, _translate("mainWindow", "mg/capsule"))
        self.pb_excipientinsert.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Insert"))

    def __init__(self):
        #upon initiation store the path to the different REST calls
        self.url_standardcomponent = "http://somewhere"
        #self.url_auth = " http://somwhere"
        #self.username = 'username'
        #self.password = 'password' #This must be changed later using Keberos-requests

        #Import the standard component
        tool.import_standardcomponent(self)  

        #Prepare the model for completer
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        #The StandardModelItem only accepts string and not int, therefore a conversion is required
        Id = [str(thing) for thing in self.SCL_Id]
        IdCompound = [str(thing) for thing in self.SCL_IdCompound]

        ziplist1 = list(zip(Id, IdCompound, self.SCL_Name))
        ziplist2 = list(zip(Id, IdCompound, self.SCL_OtherNames))

        #The idea here is to create a list with 3 columns. The 1., 2. columns being Id and IdCompounds. The 3rd comlumn is contains Name. 
        #Once done, the list will be append with OtherNames in the 3rd column. Reason being QCompleter can only match one column. Therefore 
        #Name and OtherNames have to be in 3rd column
        for name in ziplist1:
            row = list()
            for col in name:
                cell = QtGui.QStandardItem(col) #Has made sure that everything is a string
                row.append(cell)
            self.model.appendRow(row)

        for name in ziplist2:
            row = list()
            for col in name:
                cell = QtGui.QStandardItem(col)
                row.append(cell)
            self.model.appendRow(row)

        #Prepare the completer
        self.completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter()
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn(2) #Will use 2nd column containing both Name and OtherNames for completion
        self.completer.setModel(self.model)
        #I get the described error when running the below line. Also I have a question, does bracket [QtCore.QMOdelIndex] mean that the class is provided as a list? 
        self.completer.activated[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(self.onActivated)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def onActivated(self, index):
        _id = index.sibling(index.row(), 0).data()
        _id_compound = index.sibling(index.row(), 1).data()
        text = index.data()
        print(_id, _id_compound, text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_mainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(mainWindow)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activated signal is overloaded, that is, it can return `QString`(by default, in python `str`) or a `QModelIndex`. So it must be indicated by using `completer.activated [QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(...)`, obtaining the QModelIndex you can get siblings using the sibling method, or the items using the [itemFromIndex()](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemFromIndex) method.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        Id = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
        IdCompound = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
        SCL_Name = ["p", "p", "q", "q", "r", "r"]
        SCL_OtherNames = ["x", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z"]

        ziplist1 = list(zip(Id, IdCompound, SCL_Name))
        ziplist2 = list(zip(Id, IdCompound, SCL_OtherNames))

        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        for name in ziplist1 + ziplist2:
            row = list()
            for col in name:
                cell = QtGui.QStandardItem(col)
                row.append(cell)
            self.m_model.appendRow(row)

        self.m_completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(
            completionColumn=2, caseSensitivity=QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive
        )
        self.m_completer.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.m_completer.activated[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(self.onActivated)

        self.m_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.m_lineedit.setCompleter(self.m_completer)

        self.m_tableview = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.m_tableview.setModel(self.m_model)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_lineedit)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_tableview)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def onActivated(self, index):
        _id = index.sibling(index.row(), 0).data()
        _id_compound = index.sibling(index.row(), 1).data()
        text = index.data()
        print(_id, _id_compound, text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    sc = Widget()
    sc.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

You should not modify the class generated by Qt Designer<sup>(1)</sup> since it is not a widget, instead you should create another class that inherits the appropriate widget<sup>(2)</sup> and use the initial class to fill it. The decorator @pyqtSlot() only works in QObject like the widgets, in your case Ui_MainWindow is not, therefore you observe that error.

Considering that the solution is:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main_v01.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# import EBM_DB_tools as tool

class Ui_mainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(1195, 818)
        mainWindow.setWindowOpacity(2.0)
        mainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        mainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonFollowStyle)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineedit_api = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_api.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 143, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineedit_api.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_api.setObjectName("lineedit_api")
        self.pb_apiinsert = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_apiinsert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 130, 75, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pb_apiinsert.setFont(font)
        self.pb_apiinsert.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pb_apiinsert.setObjectName("pb_apiinsert")
        self.api_amount = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.api_amount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(178, 130, 142, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.api_amount.setFont(font)
        self.api_amount.setObjectName("api_amount")
        self.ItemTable = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.ItemTable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 270, 471, 281))
        self.ItemTable.setObjectName("ItemTable")
        self.dropdown_apiunit = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 130, 80, 26))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setObjectName("dropdown_apiunit")
        self.dropdown_apiunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_apiunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_apiunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_apiunit.addItem("")
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 570, 221, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel.setFont(font)
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel.setObjectName("pb_BatchRegisterLabel")
        self.pb_removeTableEntry = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_removeTableEntry.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 390, 75, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pb_removeTableEntry.setFont(font)
        self.pb_removeTableEntry.setObjectName("pb_removeTableEntry")
        self.lineedit_projectno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_projectno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 50, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_projectno.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_projectno.setText("")
        self.lineedit_projectno.setObjectName("lineedit_projectno")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 50, 21, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineedit_formulationno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_formulationno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 50, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_formulationno.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_formulationno.setText("")
        self.lineedit_formulationno.setObjectName("lineedit_formulationno")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(840, 50, 21, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineedit_apino = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_apino.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 50, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_apino.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_apino.setText("")
        self.lineedit_apino.setObjectName("lineedit_apino")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 50, 21, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineedit_batchno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_batchno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(980, 50, 71, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_batchno.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_batchno.setText("")
        self.lineedit_batchno.setObjectName("lineedit_batchno")
        self.dropdown_processtype = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.dropdown_processtype.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 291, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.dropdown_processtype.setFont(font)
        self.dropdown_processtype.setObjectName("dropdown_processtype")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(0, "")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_processtype.addItem("")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 141, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.textEdit_comment = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_comment.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 300, 511, 251))
        self.textEdit_comment.setObjectName("textEdit_comment")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 260, 151, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 20, 151, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1070, 30, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setFont(font)
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setObjectName("PushButton_NNCnoImport")
        self.pb_formulationRegister = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_formulationRegister.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 570, 221, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pb_formulationRegister.setFont(font)
        self.pb_formulationRegister.setObjectName("pb_formulationRegister")
        self.TextEdit_api = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.TextEdit_api.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 130, 191, 26))
        self.TextEdit_api.setObjectName("TextEdit_api")
        self.TextEdit_Excipient = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.TextEdit_Excipient.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 170, 191, 26))
        self.TextEdit_Excipient.setObjectName("TextEdit_Excipient")
        self.PushButton_Scan = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PushButton_Scan.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1070, 60, 91, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.PushButton_Scan.setFont(font)
        self.PushButton_Scan.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.PushButton_Scan.setObjectName("PushButton_Scan")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 100, 141, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 143, 26))

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setObjectName("lineedit_ExcipientName")
        self.lineedit_excipientamount = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit_excipientamount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 170, 142, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineedit_excipientamount.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_excipientamount.setObjectName("lineedit_excipientamount")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 170, 80, 26))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setObjectName("dropdown_excipientunit")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.addItem("")
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.addItem("")
        self.pb_excipientinsert = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb_excipientinsert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 170, 75, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pb_excipientinsert.setFont(font)
        self.pb_excipientinsert.setObjectName("pb_excipientinsert")
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(mainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1195, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(mainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_api, self.api_amount)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.api_amount, self.dropdown_apiunit)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.dropdown_apiunit, self.pb_apiinsert)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.pb_apiinsert, self.lineedit_ExcipientName)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_ExcipientName, self.lineedit_excipientamount)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_excipientamount, self.dropdown_excipientunit)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.dropdown_excipientunit, self.pb_excipientinsert)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.pb_excipientinsert, self.ItemTable)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.ItemTable, self.textEdit_comment)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.textEdit_comment, self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel, self.lineedit_projectno)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_projectno, self.lineedit_formulationno)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_formulationno, self.lineedit_apino)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_apino, self.lineedit_batchno)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineedit_batchno, self.dropdown_processtype)
        mainWindow.setTabOrder(self.dropdown_processtype, self.pb_removeTableEntry)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineedit_api.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "API NNCNo"))
        self.pb_apiinsert.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Insert"))
        self.api_amount.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Amount"))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setItemText(0, _translate("mainWindow", "mg"))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setItemText(1, _translate("mainWindow", "mg/tablet"))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setItemText(2, _translate("mainWindow", "% (w/w)"))
        self.dropdown_apiunit.setItemText(3, _translate("mainWindow", "mg/capsule"))
        self.pb_BatchRegisterLabel.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Batch Register and Label"))
        self.pb_removeTableEntry.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Remove"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "-"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "-"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "-"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(1, _translate("mainWindow", "option 1"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(2, _translate("mainWindow", "option 2"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(3, _translate("mainWindow", "option 3"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(4, _translate("mainWindow", "option 4"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(5, _translate("mainWindow", "option 5"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(6, _translate("mainWindow", "option 6"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(7, _translate("mainWindow", "option 7"))
        self.dropdown_processtype.setItemText(8, _translate("mainWindow", "User specify"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Process Type"))
        self.textEdit_comment.setHtml(_translate("mainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Comment"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "NNC No"))
        self.PushButton_NNCnoImport.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Import"))
        self.pb_formulationRegister.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Register Formulation"))
        self.TextEdit_api.setHtml(_translate("mainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.TextEdit_Excipient.setHtml(_translate("mainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.PushButton_Scan.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Scan"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Comments"))
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Excipient Name"))
        self.lineedit_excipientamount.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Amount"))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setItemText(0, _translate("mainWindow", "mg"))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setItemText(1, _translate("mainWindow", "mg/tablet"))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setItemText(2, _translate("mainWindow", "% (w/w)"))
        self.dropdown_excipientunit.setItemText(3, _translate("mainWindow", "mg/capsule"))
        self.pb_excipientinsert.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Insert"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        #upon initiation store the path to the different REST calls
        self.url_standardcomponent = "http://somewhere"
        #self.url_auth = " http://somwhere"
        #self.username = 'username'
        #self.password = 'password' #This must be changed later using Keberos-requests

        #Import the standard component
        # tool.import_standardcomponent(self)  

        self.SCL_Id = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
        self.SCL_IdCompound = ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]
        self.SCL_Name = ["111", "222", "333"]
        self.SCL_OtherNames = ["PPP", "QQQ", "RRR"]
        #Prepare the model for completer
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        #The StandardModelItem only accepts string and not int, therefore a conversion is required
        Id = [str(thing) for thing in self.SCL_Id]
        IdCompound = [str(thing) for thing in self.SCL_IdCompound]

        ziplist1 = list(zip(Id, IdCompound, self.SCL_Name))
        ziplist2 = list(zip(Id, IdCompound, self.SCL_OtherNames))

        #The idea here is to create a list with 3 columns. The 1., 2. columns being Id and IdCompounds. The 3rd comlumn is contains Name. 
        #Once done, the list will be append with OtherNames in the 3rd column. Reason being QCompleter can only match one column. Therefore 
        #Name and OtherNames have to be in 3rd column
        for name in ziplist1:
            row = list()
            for col in name:
                cell = QtGui.QStandardItem(col) #Has made sure that everything is a string
                row.append(cell)
            self.model.appendRow(row)

        for name in ziplist2:
            row = list()
            for col in name:
                cell = QtGui.QStandardItem(col)
                row.append(cell)
            self.model.appendRow(row)

        #Prepare the completer
        self.completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter()
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn(2) #Will use 2nd column containing both Name and OtherNames for completion
        self.completer.setModel(self.model)
        #I get the described error when running the below line. Also I have a question, does bracket [QtCore.QMOdelIndex] mean that the class is provided as a list? 
        self.completer.activated[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(self.onActivated)
        self.lineedit_ExcipientName.setCompleter(self.completer)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def onActivated(self, index):
        _id = index.sibling(index.row(), 0).data()
        _id_compound = index.sibling(index.row(), 1).data()
        text = index.data()
        print(_id, _id_compound, text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

<sub>(1) [Using the Generated Code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code)</sub> 
<sub>(2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46545116/6622587</sub>

Comment: Thanks you very much. This is exactly what I am looking for. When I run your code, it worked fine, but when I incorporated the same into my code, I get the following error :

Exception has occurred: TypeError
connect() failed between activated(QModelIndex) and onActivated()

QObject::connect: Cannot connect QCompleter::activated(QModelIndex) to (null)::onActivated(QModelIndex)

Comment: @jxw If you have an error then edit your question and provide a [MRE]

Comment: I just checked for the update. It worked. Thanks for giving me the opportunity to learn.