# Form2 opened using form 1 is not working on any button click pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two forms . Main_window form and second is gui form which has main functionality.

First form has one button only on which when click go to second form. the second form opens but functionality does not work on second form. But when i only run second form its functionality 100% work. I don't know the reason.

first/ welcome form code:

the untitled12 ipynb does not include gui. it has just implementation of algorithm which returns a list which is then show in this form textEdit.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import urllib
import speech_recognition as sr
import threading
import time
import import_ipynb
from gui import Ui_Function

class Ui_welcome(object):
    def openfunc(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Function()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        welcome.hide()
        self.window.show()
    def setupUi(self, welcome):
        welcome.setObjectName("welcome")
        welcome.resize(739, 600)
        welcome.setStyleSheet("Background-color: #696969;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(welcome)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 90, 601, 61))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"font-size: 25px;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"font-style: italic;\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 250, 281, 71))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"background-color: #ff6347;\n"
"Border-radius: 30px;\n"
"font-size:30px\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"background-color: #ff6347;\n"
"Border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: #ff4500;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openfunc)
        welcome.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(welcome)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(welcome)

    def retranslateUi(self, welcome):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        welcome.setWindowTitle(_translate("welcome", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("welcome", "Welcome To Book Recommendation System"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("welcome", "Let\'s get started"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    welcome = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_welcome()
    ui.setupUi(welcome)
    welcome.show()
    app.exec_()
```

second form code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import urllib
import speech_recognition as sr
import threading
import time
import import_ipynb
from Untitled12 import *

def connected(host="http://google.com"):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(host)
        return True
    except:
        return False


class Ui_Function(object):
    def setupUi(self, Function):
        Function.setObjectName("Function")
        Function.resize(737, 600)
        Function.setStyleSheet("Background-color: #696969;")

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Function)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 601, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color: #ffffff")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Enter Book Name...")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        #self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 151, 17))
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 191, 17))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"font-size: 15px;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 120, 67, 17))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"font-size: 20px;\n"
"}")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 150, 311, 21))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"font-size: 15px;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 180, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"background-color: #ff6347;\n"
"Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"background-color: #ff6347;\n"
"Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"background-color: #ff4500;\n"
"font-weight:bold;\n"
"}")


        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 320, 601, 231))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit{\n"
"Background-color: #ffffff;\n"
"}")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 290, 141, 21))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"font-size: 15px;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(538, 110, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"background-color: #ff6347;\n"
"Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"Background-color: #ff6347;\n"
"Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"background-color: #ff4500;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"}")


        #self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(Untitled12.give_rec("Angel of Hope"))

        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 220, 241, 21))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"}")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 180, 251, 31))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("QcomboBox{\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"Background-color: #ffffff;\n"
"font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"}")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Your Book Name here...")
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.changeText)

        Function.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Function)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Function)

    def changeText(self, index):
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.comboBox.itemText(index))

    def retranslateUi(self, Function):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Function.setWindowTitle(_translate("Function", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Function", "Enter the Book Name:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Function", "OR"))
        self.label_3.setText(
            _translate("Function", "Write the Book Name by your Voice:")
        )
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Function", "Click and Say"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Function", "Recommendations:"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Function", "Search"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Function", "Suggestions..."))


class SpeechWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    itemsChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    def speech(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._speech, daemon=True).start()

    def _speech(self):
        if connected():
            r = sr.Recognizer()
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                self.messageChanged.emit("Listening...")
                time.sleep(1)
                # read the audio data from the default microphone
                try:
                    audio_data = r.listen(source, timeout=5)
                except sr.WaitTimeoutError as e:
                    print("Timeout; {0}".format(e))
                self.messageChanged.emit("Time over")
                time.sleep(1)
                self.messageChanged.emit("Recognizing...")
                time.sleep(1)
                # convert speech to text
                text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language="en-UK", show_all=True)
                try:
                    self.messageChanged.emit("You said:")
                    self.itemsChanged.emit([])
                    list1 = []
                    if len(text) > 0:
                        print(len(text["alternative"]))
                        for x in range(0, len(text["alternative"])):
                            list1.append(text["alternative"][x]["transcript"])
                        self.itemsChanged.emit(list1)
                    else:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        self.messageChanged.emit("\tNothing")

                except LookupError:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    self.messageChanged.emit("Could not Understand Value")

                except sr.UnknownValueError:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    self.messageChanged.emit(
                        "Voice Recognition could not understand audio"
                    )

                except sr.RequestError as e:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    self.messageChanged.emit(
                        "Voice Recognition could not request results ; {0}".format(e)
                    )
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.messageChanged.emit(
                "NO Internet Connection. \nCheck your Internet Connection"
            )
        time.sleep(1)
        self.messageChanged.emit("Completed")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.messageChanged.emit("Suggestions...")


class Function(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Function):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Function, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.worker = SpeechWorker()
        self.worker.messageChanged.connect(self.updateMessage)
        self.worker.itemsChanged.connect(self.updateItems)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.worker.speech)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.updateEditBox)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def updateMessage(self, message):
        self.label_5.setText(message)
        self.label_5.adjustSize()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
    def updateItems(self, items):
        self.comboBox.clear()
        self.comboBox.addItems(items)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def updateEditBox(self):
        print(self.lineEdit.text())
        string=give_rec(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.textEdit.clear()
        self.textEdit.setText("\tRecommendations of "+self.lineEdit.text().title()+"\t")
        i=1
        for names in string:
            self.textEdit.append(str(i)+" - "+str(names))
            i=i+1
        self.comboBox.clear()
        self.lineEdit.setText("")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Function()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

here's the functionality of form2 which works when i only run second form.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation:

The Ui_Function class that is generated by Qt Designer only aims to fill in a widget so you are using it to fill in "self.window" so it will not have the logic that I implement in the Function class.

I recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46545116/6622587) and [Using the Generated Code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) so you know because it is not recommended to modify the class generated by Qt Designer but to create another class that inherits from the appropriate widget and implements the necessary logic.

#### Solution:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from gui import Function


class Ui_welcome(object):
    def setupUi(self, welcome):
        welcome.setObjectName("welcome")
        welcome.resize(739, 600)
        welcome.setStyleSheet("Background-color: #696969;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(welcome)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 90, 601, 61))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(
            "\n"
            "font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
            "font-size: 25px;\n"
            "font-weight: bold;\n"
            "font-style: italic;\n"
            "color: #ffffff;\n"
            ""
        )
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 250, 281, 71))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton{\n"
            "color: #ffffff;\n"
            "background-color: #ff6347;\n"
            "Border-radius: 30px;\n"
            "font-size:30px\n"
            "}\n"
            "QPushButton:hover{\n"
            "color: #ffffff;\n"
            "background-color: #ff6347;\n"
            "Border-radius: 30px;\n"
            "background-color: #ff4500;\n"
            "font-weight: bold;\n"
            "}"
        )
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        welcome.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(welcome)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(welcome)

    def retranslateUi(self, welcome):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        welcome.setWindowTitle(_translate("welcome", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(
            _translate("welcome", "Welcome To Book Recommendation System")
        )
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("welcome", "Let's get started"))


class Welcome(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_welcome):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Welcome, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openfunc)
        self.window = Function()

    def openfunc(self):
        self.window.show()
        self.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Welcome()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sub>I recommend you review your OOP annotations or take a course on that subject since if you are going to use PyQt it is a minimum and necessary requirement.</sub>

Comment: Okay. I know about OOP in python very well. But pyqt5 is something that i am unable to understand. Some widgets work but some not they needs threading. Even opening a new form is also difficult. Actually i have worked on c# windows form thats why i am thinking in sense of them.

Comment: @HinaKhadim Do you know what the purpose of the threads is? and especially in the case of the GUI.

Comment: Yes i know the purpose of threads but in case of GUI i don't know. Because as i say i am new to pyqt5. it's the first gui tool which i have started learning. I have learnt c# windows form. In these there is no issues such like which i am facing in pyqt5. pyqt5 is different. but i will learn.

Comment: @HinaKhadim In general the objective of the threads is so that exclusive tasks are not blocked. In the case of any GUI, the event loop consumes the entire main thread, so exclusive tasks (tasks that are time-consuming) cannot be executed on the same thread but will have to be executed on another thread. This concept also applies to C# or any other technology. Surely in C# you have not encountered a task that consumes a lot that you have to execute through the GUI.

Comment: Got it. Yes , in  c# i would not have do tasks for which i need threading. Thank you so much