# PyQt5 - Separating logic from ui leads to functions not working

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, logic

I tried to separate my program's functionality from the Ui class (generated by PyQt5 Designer), as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544780/qtdesigner-changes-will-be-lost-after-redesign-user-interface/46545116#46545116) and [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code).
Problem is that when run logic.py the Ui shows up, but the program's functions do not work at all.
I am using PyCharm, so I tried invalidating the caches, installing pyqt5-stubs but that did not work as well. Any help would be highly appreciated!

**ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("File Manager")
        MainWindow.resize(1120, 800)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 121, 41))

        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 221, 471))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        path = r"C:\Test_folder"
        self.dirModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.dirModel.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
        self.listView.setModel(self.dirModel)
        self.listView.setRootIndex(self.dirModel.index(path))


        self.fileModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.fileModel)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 90, 801, 571))
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("File Manager", "File Manager"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+ New File"))
```

**logic.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
import sys

class Logic(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # Set up the user interface
        self.setupUi(self)

        # "New Project" button function call
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.make_document)

        # When folder in listView is clicked, the items stored in it are
        # displayed in the treeview.
        self.listView.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    # Program Functions
    def on_click(self, index):
        """When a directory is selected in the list view, show all of its files
        in the tree view."""
        path = self.dirModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.setRootPath(path))

    def make_document(self):
        print("Making document")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making some mistakes.

First of all, you never created an instance of `Logic`.

Then, in order to use the files generated by pyuic a QWidget has to be created, so that the UI can be built in it with the UI_* object.

You don't need to subclass Ui_MainWindow, but the widget class that you're going to use (QMainWindow, in your case). You can then choose to use the single or multiple inheritance approach, but I suggest you to use the latter.

Single inheritance:

```
class Logic(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Logic, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.button1.clicked.connect(self.make_document)
        # ...
```

Multiple inheritance:

```
class Logic(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Logic, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.make_document)
```

Obviously, this implies that it's the `Logic()` instance that has to be created when starting the application, not `Ui_MainWindow`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    logic = Logic()
    logic.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For more insight, carefully read the official documentation about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Would you be so kind as to elaborate on your first two points? I implemented the inheritance properly, but it is still not working. Otherwise, I read the documentation (as linked above) but I am still having trouble figuring it out. Thank you.

Comment: Have you created the instance of Logic() in the `if __name__...` statement? Note that you only have to create that instance, there's no need to `ui = Ui_MainWindow()` in there, as the Logic class takes care of that. Read the edit at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now and it works perfectly. Thank you so very much! :)