# Can you bring a .py file into Qt Designer

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

I design a GUI in Qt Designer, convert to .py in cmd and start writing python code to run the GUI button's etc.

What happens if I want to modify the GUI again without typing all the GUI code myself - can I bring the .py file into Qt Designer again and export out, still retaining the code I've added?

Comment: No, it can not be done. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544780/qtdesigner-changes-will-be-lost-after-redesign-user-interface

Comment: To add to the answer linked by @eyllanesc: the usual workflow when using a ui designed in QtDesigner is to leave the .ui/.py files as they are, and import them in a separate script where you can add whatever functionality you need.